# CSS grids get broken on a next page view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website broken up into CSS grids. The grids are fairly simple, just used to rearrange content in a different order under mobile.

Here is the general layout of the mobile grid:

```
.product-page-container {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns:100%;
      grid-template-rows:75px min-content min-content min-content min-content min-content min-content min-content 75px;
      grid-template-areas:
    "banner"
    "productDetails"
    "productHero"
    "productPurchase"
    "productDescription"
    "productVideo"
    "features"
    "meta"
    "footerBanner"
  }
```

I just have the row's size to the general content.

Under 'features' I have a nav that you can filter through a variety of different views (product features, spec and review).

This is where I found this strange bug that is giving me a nightmare. Under review, if you click on 'next' the sizing of the rows just goes crazy. The footer banner stretches much past 75px and the 'productDetails' and 'productHero' get shifted upward.

This is built within Shopify, here is a link to see what I'm referring too.

https://rq852rt3ja4kgxnq-11502512.shopifypreview.com

You'd have to go into the mobile view to see the bug. I believe it has to with the reload and pagination considering that the next page view may be larger/ shorter in height.

I've attempted several fixed by setting 'minmax(700px,min-content)' on certain rows to see if that changes anything but I couldn't get any results.

**What is causing this strange behavior?** I can't seem to pinpoint the cause of this issue and how my bottom row `footerBanner` ends up growing to such a large height after the next page pagination. I have attempted recreated a similar situation and it seems to behave fine.

```js
function ChangeSize () {
  document.getElementById("strangeBox").style.height = "100px";
}
```

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:100%;
  grid-template-rows: 10px min-content min-content 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "top"
  "box"
  "variable"
  "bottom"
}

.topBox {
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  grid-area: top;
}

.box {
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
  grid-area: box;
 }
 
 .strangeBox {
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  grid-area:variable;
 }
 
 .bottomBox {
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  grid-area: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topBox">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="strangeBox" id="strangeBox">
    <button onclick="ChangeSize()">ChangeSize</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I made the question more clear, but to be more direct is I can't seem to figure out why clicking 'next' causes my bottom banner to explode in height and move all my content up.

Comment: The overlays are the cause. They are the only elements that are causing the incorrect sizing. Can't tell you how to fix without fully working dev mode.

Comment: FYI - I can only produce this when moving from landscape to portrait. Simply clicking "next" does not cause the issue for me.

Comment: @RandyCasburn when you mention the overlays what are you referring too?  I found just using chromes inspect mode and going to any phone size caused the bug to appear for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the footerBanner container didn't have any constraints. Adding

```
.footerBanner img {
max-height:100%;
width:100%;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

solved the issue.